# Cannot step over breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, debugging

I am using Eclipse to develop for Android. My test platform is the Android emulator using 4.2.2. Whenever I start the program in debug, it breaks on breakpoints just fine. However, if I try to step over/into/out or resume, it will immediately break upon the same breakpoint. As in, the next line is never reached.

However, if I toggle the breakpoint off, it will resume, etc. just fine. This is a really annoying workaround, as it means I have to have to constantly disable/reenable breakpoints.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before, and is there a fix?

Edit: I am on OSX Lion.

Edit 2: Some additional research seems to suggest it is related to a log message from LogCat:

```
03-06 21:47:07.861: D/dalvikvm(1232): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was eventually able to workaround this by downloading the full ADT from Android's website - I originally downloaded Eclipse and the SDK separately, so there may be something fixed in the configuration. Also, the Eclipse version packaged with the ADT was newer (Juno, I was using Helios). Not sure if any of this is significant, but may be if anyone else encounters this.